# ファイルのパーミッションがわかりません。

Tags: php, html

以下のファイルをエックスサーバーのFTPでアップロードして、パーミッションも変えたのですが、Webサイトを開くと、「403 Forbidden」と表示されます。(ちなみに下のPHPはモジュール版なのですが、CGIとして起動させたいので、644から755に変更しました。)パーミッションが間違っているんでしょうか？教えてください。あと、phpファイルだけを644に変更してやってもダメでした。
引用元は http://script.s16.xrea.com/2ch/ です。

```
bbs18(755)/┬admin(755)/┬admin.php(755) 
            │           ├abon.php(755)
            │           ├cap.php(755)
            │           ├deleboard.php(755)
            │           ├deny.php(755)
            │           ├edit.php(755)
            │           ├hostlog.php(755)
            │           ├image.php(755)
            │           ├main.php(755)
            │           ├makeboard.php(755)
            │           ├menu.php(755)
            │           ├passcheck.php(755)
            │           ├setboard.php(755)
            │           ├setboard2.php(755)
            │           ├threadm.php(755)
            │           ├vip.php(755)
            │           ├main.css(755)
            │           ├menu.css(755)
            │           └passfile.cgi(755)
            │
            ├test(755)/ ┬bbs.php(755)
            │           ├bbs2.php(755)
            │           ├read.php(755)
            │           ├make_html.php(755)
            │           ├make_work.php(755)
            │           ├new_thread.php(755)
            │           ├config_r.php(755)
            │           ├b.php(755)
            │           ├p.php(755)
            │           ├r.php(755)
            │           ├index.txt(600)
            │           ├form.txt(600)
            │           ├caps.cgi(755)
            │           ├headad.txt(600)
            │           ├putad.txt(600)
            │           ├option.txt(600)
            │           └omikuji(755)/┬omikuji.txt(600)
            │                          ├base.txt(600)
            │                          ├who.txt(600)
            │                          ├where.txt(600)
            │                          ├do.txt(600)
            │                          └food.txt(600)
            │
            ├2ch.gif(644)
            ├ba.gif(644)
            │
            └board(755)/-├kako(755)/┬index.php(755)
                         │          └kako.txt(600)
                         ├i(755)/─index.html(644)
                         ├SETTING.TXT(600)
                         ├config.php(755)
                         ├subject.txt(666)
                         ├subback.html(644)
                         ├index.html(644)
                         ├head.txt(600)
                         ├RIP.cgi(755)
                         ├timecheck.cgi(755)
                         ├hostlog.cgi(755)
                         ├uerror.cgi(755)
                         └threadconf.cgi(755)
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。前に、それで聞いてみて、やってみたのですがやはりできません。

Comment: (1)重複候補の元質問にも私は回答をつけましたが、そちらは確認して頂けましたか, (2)`アップロード先`と`実際のURL`との対応関係は理解していますか？, (3)ファイル一覧を載せられていますが、具体的にどのファイルにアクセスしようとしているのでしょうか。

Comment: （１）確認はしましたが、やはりできません。（２）完ぺきとまでは言えませんが、大体理解してます。　（３）これら、すべてをアップロードすると、admin.phpにアクセスして、そこから設定画面にアクセスできるみたいなのですが、その前に「403 Forbidden」が出てきて開けません。

Comment: 詳しくないので回答できませんが、Xserver独自の問題のようにも感じますので サポートに問い合わせされてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。今、サーバーに問い合わせ中なのですが、まだ返信が来ないんですよね......

Comment: https://www.xserver.ne.jp/manual/man_server_log.php エラーログが取得できるようですね。参考にしてみては?